# What does it mean when a set is the exponent?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Can you help me understand what the exponent means here?

$$ (A\cap B) \cup D^C $$

A, B, C and D are all sets of a universal set U.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure that $C$ is a set, and not a symbol for the [complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(set_theory))? In general, $X^Y$ often means "the set of functions $Y \to X$", perhaps with some additional properties like continuity. That doesn't seem to be the case here.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it must be the complement. I can close this unless you would like to make an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Small lower-case $c$ as an exponent when a Universe of Discourse is understood generally represents *complement relative to $U$*. That seems to be almost certainly the meaning in what you write: $(A\cap B)\cup D^c$ would be the collection of all things that are in either in both $A$ and $B$, or else that are *not* in $D$, as
$$D^c = \{x\in U \mid x\notin D\}.$$
If that's the case (a lower-case $c$), then $D^c$ is pronounced "complement of $D$" or "$D$-complement."

Note the difference between
$$D^c\quad\text{and}\quad D^C.$$
If $C$ is a set, then $D^C$ is, as others have noted, the set of all functions with domain $C$ and image contained in $D$,
$$D^C = \{f\colon C\to D\mid f\text{ is a function}\}.$$

Answer (score 3):

Generally, when we write $D^C$ for two sets $D,C$, what we mean is the set of functions $f:C \rightarrow D$.  Consider for example $C$ being a two-element set, $\{ 1,2 \}$.  Then the set of functions from $C$ to $D$ is just the set of ordered pairs $(d_1,d_2)$ of elements of $D$ -- and hence has cardinality $|D|^2$.  In general, the cardinality of $D^C$ is $|D|^{|C|}$ for finite sets, and we use that to generalize cardinality exponentiation for infinite sets.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but as Dylan Moreland suggested, it's probably the complement (the course hasn't covered anything in your answer).

Answer (score 2):

In the general set theoretic settings, $X^Y=\{f\colon Y\to X\mid f\ \text{is a function}\}$. That is, this is the set of all functions with domain $Y$ and range which is a subset of $X$.

In the introductory context, in which there is usually a universal set being involved (although these can be involved in an explicit way much further into mathematics, however I doubt you would have asked this question in that situation), it is common to denote with a **lowercase** $c$ the *complement* with respect to the universal set, that is $D^c=U\setminus D=\{x\in U\mid x\notin D\}$, where $U$ is the universal set.