# What does this notation mean $\{a_k\}_{k=i}^n$?

Tags: notation

What does this notation mean  $\{a_k\}_{k=i}^n$?

I saw it in sites talking about sequences but there was no explanation of what it meant.

E: I reviewed the other post, this is not a duplicate, and the chosen answer described what I asked.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Notation for sequences](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/115978/notation-for-sequences)

Comment: The other question asks what notation to _write_ for _infinite_ sequences; this question concerns how to _read_ a notation which (it happens) is for _finite_ sequences (or subsequences). This does not seem a duplicate to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

${\{a_k\}}_{k=i}^n$ means the list of terms in the sequence $a_k$, ranging from $k=i$ to $k=n$; i.e.:

$$a_i,a_{i+1},a_{i+2},...,a_n$$

Comment: I see! That was really simple. Thanks!

Comment: You are very welcome.

Comment: I would assume $\{a_k\}_{k=i}^n$ was the set $\{a_i, \dots a_n\}$, but $(a_k)_{k=i}^n$ was the list $(a_i, \dots, a_n)$.

Answer (score 2):

It means the following collection of objects: 
$$\{a_k\}_{k=i}^n=\left \{ a_i,a_{i+1},a_{i+2},\dots,a_n \right \}$$

- For example, if $i=1$ and $n=5$, we would have:
  $$\{a_k\}_{k=1}^5=\left \{ a_1,a_{2},a_{3},a_{4},a_5 \right \}$$