# Learning what $\{a_{k}\}^{n}_{0}$ means

Tags: notation

Somewhere I saw the notation $\{a_{k}\}^{n}_{0}$ used. I believe it was used for a summation, but I'm not sure. What does this actually mean and can also use it to describe the set $\{a_0,a_1,...,a_n\}$?

Comment: Yes, it typically just means $\{a_0, a_1,...,a_n\}$.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 Ah, thank you.

Comment: See also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1322747

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a short way to denote the sequence of elements $$a_k,$$ as $k$ runs over some index set. Here, $k$ runs from $0$ to $n.$